# id attribute returns value 0 inside a map function in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5.8

**Code**

```
   $drillDownChart = Loan::select('loan_type AS name')
                           ->groupBy('loan_type')
                           ->where('transaction_year', $transyear)
                           ->where('invalid', false)
                           ->get();

    $drillDownChart->map(function($val)use($loanChartArr) {
        $val->id = $val->name;
        $val->data = $loanChartArr;
        return $val;
    });
```

**Output** `var_dump(json_encode($drillDownChart));`

```
string(340) "[{"name":"Hospitalization","id":0,"data":[[1,0],[2,0],[3,0],[4,0],[5,2],[6,1],[7,3],[8,1],[9,1],[10,0],[11,0],[12,0]]},{"name":"Salary","id":0,"data":[[1,0],[2,0],[3,0],[4,0],[5,2],[6,1],[7,3],[8,1],[9,1],[10,0],[11,0],[12,0]]},{"name":"Emergency","id":0,"data":[[1,0],[2,0],[3,0],[4,0],[5,2],[6,1],[7,3],[8,1],[9,1],[10,0],[11,0],[12,0]]}]"
```

The `$val->id = $val->name;` should return "Hospitalization", "Salary" and "Emergency" but instead it returns 0. Notice if I change "id" to "ID", it shows the correct output.

```
$drillDownChart->map(function($val)use($loanChartArr) {
    $val->ID = $val->name;
    $val->data = $loanChartArr;
    return $val;
});
```

Output:

```
string(373) "[{"name":"Hospitalization","ID":"Hospitalization","data":[[1,0],[2,0],[3,0],[4,0],[5,2],[6,1],[7,3],[8,1],[9,1],[10,0],[11,0],[12,0]]},{"name":"Salary","ID":"Salary","data":[[1,0],[2,0],[3,0],[4,0],[5,2],[6,1],[7,3],[8,1],[9,1],[10,0],[11,0],[12,0]]},{"name":"Emergency","ID":"Emergency","data":[[1,0],[2,0],[3,0],[4,0],[5,2],[6,1],[7,3],[8,1],[9,1],[10,0],[11,0],[12,0]]}]"
```

What is wrong in here? Is "id" restricted to be used in laravel in this case? Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Laravel assumes your model has a primary key named `id` with a value of type `int`.

Therefore, the `id` attribute is casted to an `int`. It is like having this default casts:

```php
protected $casts = [
    'id' => 'int'
];
```

So when you access `id`, your `string` (e.g. "Hospitalization") is casted to `int`. The result is `0`.

If you really want to keep your current code, you'll have to do some hacky stuff, like setting a accessor for the `id` attribute:

```php
public function getIdAttribute($value)
{
    return $value;
}
```

This way, the cast will be overriden and you will be able to retrieve the name the way you want.

*However, I would advice against manually changing the `id` at runtime, it is obviously a code smell, a sign that something isn't quite right with this part of your project.*

---

For those who like digging further, this is where all what I explained happens:

`vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php`

```php
/**
* Get the casts array.
*
* @return array
*/
public function getCasts()
{
    if ($this->getIncrementing()) {
        return array_merge([$this->getKeyName() => $this->getKeyType()], $this->casts);
    }

    return $this->casts;
}
```

When you try to access an attribute (`$this->id`), Laravel will determine if it has an accessor, if this is a relationship or not... and at the end, will cast it to the correct type.

To get the casts, it will call `->getCasts()`.

First this method will check if your model is auto incrementing (which can be disabled by setting the property `$incrementing` to `false`).

If that's the case, it will get the primary key name (`->getKeyName()` which is `id` by default) and its type (`->getKeyType()` which is `int` by default).

This key pair will be merged with the `$casts` property of the model.